# Where clause isn't returning any records in active record even though there are matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I'm trying to write a test for my code.  The class method is below.

```
def get_alerts
  p JobSearch.all
  p JobSearch.where('cancelled_date is null and created_at > ? and email_address is not null', DateTime.now - 90)
  JobSearch.where('cancelled_date is null and created_at > ? and email_address is not null', DateTime.now - 90)
end
```

My test looks like...

```
it 'returns alerts with a null cancelled_date' do
  JobSearch.create!(cancelled_date: DateTime.now, email_address: 'test@test.com', job_board_id: job_board.id, created_at: DateTime.now - 80)
  JobSearch.create!(cancelled_date: DateTime.now, email_address: 'test@test.com', job_board_id: job_board.id, created_at: DateTime.now - 80)
  JobSearch.create!(job_board_id: job_board.id, email_address: 'test@test.com', created_at: DateTime.now - 2)
  JobSearch.create!(job_board_id: job_board.id, email_address: 'test@test.com', created_at: DateTime.now - 2)
  JobSearch.create!(job_board_id: job_board.id, email_address: 'test@test.com', created_at: DateTime.now - 1)
  alerts = task.get_alerts
  expect(alerts.count).to be(3)
end
```

When I run the test I get nil from my get_alerts method.  But what is written to the console for the JobSearch.all query gives me the following.

```
<JobSearch id: 1, keyword: nil, pageSize: 0, showAllJobs: false, page: 0, position_title: nil, job_type: nil, salary: nil, include_remote: false, filter_location: nil, radius_location: nil, salary_min: nil, salary_max: nil, email_address: "test@test.com", job_id: nil, cancelled_date: "2015-06-23 18:32:29", job_board_id: 1, last_run_date: nil, added_since: nil, created_at: "2015-04-04 18:32:29">, #<JobSearch id: 2, keyword: nil, pageSize: 0, showAllJobs: false, page: 0, position_title: nil, job_type: nil, salary: nil, include_remote: false, filter_location: nil, radius_location: nil, salary_min: nil, salary_max: nil, email_address: "test@test.com", job_id: nil, cancelled_date: "2015-06-23 18:32:29", job_board_id: 1, last_run_date: nil, added_since: nil, created_at: "2015-04-04 18:32:29">, #<JobSearch id: 3, keyword: nil, pageSize: 0, showAllJobs: false, page: 0, position_title: nil, job_type: nil, salary: nil, include_remote: false, filter_location: nil, radius_location: nil, salary_min: nil, salary_max: nil, email_address: "test@test.com", job_id: nil, cancelled_date: nil, job_board_id: 1, last_run_date: nil, added_since: nil, created_at: "2015-06-21 18:32:29">, #<JobSearch id: 4, keyword: nil, pageSize: 0, showAllJobs: false, page: 0, position_title: nil, job_type: nil, salary: nil, include_remote: false, filter_location: nil, radius_location: nil, salary_min: nil, salary_max: nil, email_address: "test@test.com", job_id: nil, cancelled_date: nil, job_board_id: 1, last_run_date: nil, added_since: nil, created_at: "2015-06-21 18:32:29">, #<JobSearch id: 5, keyword: nil, pageSize: 0, showAllJobs: false, page: 0, position_title: nil, job_type: nil, salary: nil, include_remote: false, filter_location: nil, radius_location: nil, salary_min: nil, salary_max: nil, email_address: "test@test.com", job_id: nil, cancelled_date: nil, job_board_id: 1, last_run_date: nil, added_since: nil, created_at: "2015-06-22 18:32:29">]>
```

So what am I doing wrong in my where clause?

Comment: Do you have a validation uniqueness on `email_address` in `JobSearch`?

Comment: No.  In fact, even if I reduce the where clause to just where(cancelled_date: nil), I still get back nil.

Comment: Another interesting thing about this is that if I run the exact same query in the rails console, with having the same test data, I get results.

Comment: You mentioned about `rails console`, is it in development or test mode?

Comment: in development mode.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that your database schema in test and development mode are different resulting a failure during creating `job_search`. Can you run the same test code in `rails console test`?